# E[$X_n$] of submartingale is increasing

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

Let $X_n$ a positive submartingale.
What I don't understand is why $$E[|X_n|]$$ is increasing in n.

Could someone help me to understand it?

Comment: Since $\mathbb P(X_n\geqslant 0)=1$, the absolute value in $\mathbb E[|X_n|]$ is redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the definition of submartingale, $E(X_{n+1} \vert \mathcal{F}_n) \ge X_n$. You take expectation on both sides of the inequality. Then you get
$$E(X_{n+1}) = E\left(E(X_{n+1} \vert \mathcal{F}_n)\right) \ge E(X_n).$$

Comment: Nice, elegant, straight to the point answer. +1